# While command not found and syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a shell script that takes a string input from a user, asks for a file name and reports whether
that string is present in the file. Below is my current script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash  
while :  
       do  
       echo "Please enter a string"  
       read input_string  
       echo "Please enter the file name to see if that string is present in it -  (Enter .abw after)"  
     read input_string1  
     grep -q "${input_string}" "${input_string1}"       
     if grep -q $input_string $input_string1 ; then  
         echo  "Your string has been found"    
     else   
         echo "Your string has not been found"  
      fi  
 done
```

when I run the script it says

```
Line 2: while:: command not found
Line 3: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'
Line 3: 'do'
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: why not use `while true` instead of `while : ` ?

Comment: better yet, do `while echo "Please enter a string:"\ndo read...` - `echo` will return 0 as often as `:` or `true` will. Still, it seems strange. Is there some kind of problem with `\r`eturn characters in the file? Or does `/bin/bash` definitely exist?

Comment: while true worked, it is now saying that there is a bad substitution in line 8?

Comment: quote those variables after the second `grep -q` *(why two `grep`s?)*

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that your script has `while:`, not `while :`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need both grep lines, instead you might as well put:

```
if grep -q "$input_string" "$input_string1" ; then

echo "Your string has been found"

else

echo "Your string has not been found"

fi
```